# Deploy issue with custom config file

Tags: appveyor

We have non-Web project with custom config file. This file has XML transformations.

After build, this file should appear in Web bin folder. When we build app using VS2015 and publish it to Azure, everything is working as expected.

When we try to deploy it using Appveyor, custom config file is not copied to bin folder and not deployed.

We have used SlowCheetah for transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Problem was fixed by adding SlowCheetah as a Nuget package.